# Express : Calling functions on app.param in multiple routes with same para name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have 2 routes defined in 2 separate files but a parameter **RecordId** is same for both the routes:

I am expecting that :
1) whenever I call **/api/CountryMaster/:RecordId**,
only **RecordByIdCtry** function should be called. &

2) when I am calling **/api/commonMaster/:MasterName/:RecordId**,
only **RecordByIdCmn** function should be called.

However, both functions are getting called with the order being as set in javascript. 
i.e.

```
 require('../app/routes/commonMaster.server.routes.js')(app);
    require('../app/routes/countryMaster.server.routes.js')(app);
```

How can i stop these & ensure that only one method is called.

**//CountryMaster.js**

```
var ctrl = require('../../app/controllers/CountryMaster.server.ctrl.js');
var users = require('../../app/controllers/user.server.ctrl.js');
module.exports = function (app)
{

    app.route('/api/CountryMaster')
    .get(users.requiresLogin,ctrl.list) 
    .post(users.requiresLogin,ctrl.create);


     app.route('/api/CountryMaster/:RecordId')
    .get(ctrl.read)
    .put(users.requiresLogin, ctrl.hasAuthorization, ctrl.update)
    .delete(users.requiresLogin, ctrl.hasAuthorization, ctrl.delete);

    app.param('RecordId', ctrl.RecordByIdCtry);
}
```

**//CommonMaster.js**

```
var ctrl = require('../../app/controllers/commonMaster.server.ctrl.js');
var users = require('../../app/controllers/user.server.ctrl.js');
module.exports = function (app)
{
    app.route('/api/commonMaster/:MasterName')
    .get(users.requiresLogin,ctrl.list) 
    .post(users.requiresLogin,ctrl.create);
    app.route('/api/commonMaster/:MasterName/:RecordId')
    .get(ctrl.read)
    .put(users.requiresLogin, ctrl.hasAuthorization, ctrl.update)
        .delete(users.requiresLogin, ctrl.hasAuthorization, ctrl.delete);
    app.param('MasterName', ctrl.MasterName);
    app.param('RecordId', ctrl.RecordByIdCmn);
}
```

How can I ensure that only one method is called..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `app` is always the same app, so you're basically declaring two handlers for the same parameter, which isn't going to work.

You should use entirely separate [routers](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) instead:

```
// CountryMaster.js
...
module.exports = function(app) {
  var router = require('express').Router();

  router.route('/')
        .get(...)
        .post(...);

  router.route('/:RecordId')
        .get(...)
        .put(...)
        .delete(...);

  // The magic:
  router.param('RecordId', ctrl.RecordByIdCtry);

  // Mount the router on `/api/CountryMaster`
  app.use('/api/CountryMaster', router);
};
```

And similar for `CommonMaster.js`.